# Extracting source from pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable, source

I like using pgfplotstable because I can feed data in tables directly to it and generate a latex table. However, not all of my coauthors have the right packages to compile pgf-enabled latex.

Since pgfplotstable merely generates latex source for the tabular environment, I was wondering if there was a way to extract the output source and plug that directly into a latex file ?

**Update**: I thought Christian's answer would work, but it doesn't appear to. Here's an MWE - the original file compiles and produces output, but the source code is not captured in the file `tablespace.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
 \pgfplotstabletypeset[outfile=tablespace.tex,columns = {a,b}]{
a b
    5000 1.234e5
    6000 1.631e5
    7000 2.1013e5
    9000 1000000
}
\end{document}
```

**Up-Update: problem solved although I'm not sure how.**

Comment: My intent with this MWE was to capture the LaTeX source for the table in the file tablespace.tex. that file is not created.

Comment: hmm. I'm using pdflatex/latex as the command, with or without -shell-escape (doesn't make a difference)

Comment: There isn't: in fact there's no mention of tablespace at all, which is what's confusing me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6398/discussion-between-suresh-and-egreg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: use the `outfile={<outputfilename>}` option.

If your coauthors do not have PGF installed, you can set

```
\let\pgfutilensuremath=\ensuremath
```

and the resulting output file will be completely independent of `pgfplotstable`.

You can even use the feature to modify the output files manually - and to tell `pgfplotstable` that the existing output file should be included as-is, without considering the input data. If you need that as well (perhaps in order to get a first starting point of the conversion), you can use the option `include outfiles`.